# Conditional Subtraction in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for some assistance programming a report. I'm in the early stages. I've hit a wall when attempting to conditionally subtract using VBA. I would like to Subtract 1 from Column C if Column B is greater than 1. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The code I have so far is below

```
Sub UniqueContactReport()
Columns("Z:AQ").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("X").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("V").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("U").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("J:S").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.Delete

    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B") > 1 And Cells(i, "D") = 0 Then
            Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean `debug.print Cells(i, "C").value - 1` You should run your code step by step and  tell us what is the exact issue that you are facing

Comment: Hi Raunak. The code I have above runs fine but I'm not sure where to start to code my next step which is to subtract the number 1 from Column C if the value in Column B is greater than 1 (for the entire range of Column B (B2:B3000).Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To succinctly address your question:

```
Sub ModifyColumnC()
Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' See comment below
    For i = 1 to N 'no need to go backwards because you are not deleting
        If Cells(i, "B").Value > 1 Then
            Cells(i, "C").Value = Cells(i,"C").Value -1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have added `.Value` simply because I try to avoid implicit code. But yes, `.Value` is the default behaviour. I have left the code that determines the end row because all the following rows are going to be blank (thus <1) and this saves processing time (potentially a lot of it).

An alternative piece of code to do exactly the same thing.

```
Sub ModifyColumnC()
Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 
    For i = 1 to N 
        Cells(i, "C").Value = Cells(i,"C").Value - IIf(Cells(i, "B").Value > 1,1,0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

A nuance is that in the `IIf` command, all paths are evaluated. But in this case, both the true and false statements are simple constants and unlikely to raise any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems this is what you want.

```
Sub UniqueContactReport()
Columns("Z:AQ").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("X").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("V").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("U").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("J:S").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.Delete

    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B") > 1 And Cells(i, "D") = 0 Then
            debug.print Cells(i, "C").value - 1
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make no loop and use `AutoFilter()`:

```
Sub UniqueContactReport()        
    With Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) 'reference column B cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">1" ' filter referenced range on their value being >1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then ' if any filtered cell other then the header (first one)
            With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(, 1) ' reference filtered cells corresponding ones one colum to the right
                .Value = .Value - 1 ' lower referenced cell value by one
            End With
            If .Cells(1, 1).Value > 1 Then .Cells(1, 2) = .cell(1, 2) - 1 ' check if first cell is to be treated, too (first cell of filtered range is assumed as the "header" so doesn't get caught in filter action)
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove autofilter
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW you can collapse all those `EntireColumn.Delete` statements into one:

```
Range("Z1:AQ1,X1, V1, U1, J:S, A:H").EntireColumn.Delete
```

but in this case you have to properly adjust the columns reference in the list since columns get deleted in one shot i.e. what-you-list-is-what-gets-deleted while in your previous approach the order of the delete statements affects which original columns gets actually deleted